# Postgres 11 issue: "SSL error: DATA_LENGTH_TOO_LONG" error on server

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Looking for any thoughts on what is going on here:

Environment:

- Java 11 GCP Function that copies data into table
- Postgres 11 Cloud SQL using JDBC driver
  (org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5)
- No changes to any code or configuration in 2 weeks.
- I'm connecting to the private SQL IP address, so similar to
  jdbc:postgresql://10.90.123.4/...
- I'm not requiring a SSL cert
- There is Serverless VPC Access set up between the Function and SQL.
- This is happening across two different GCP projects and SQL servers.

Prior to this Saturday (2/22), everything was working fine. We are using Postgres' CopyManager to load data into a table: copyManager.copyIn(sql, this.reader);

After 2/22, this started failing with "SSL error: DATA_LENGTH_TOO_LONG" as seen in the SQL server log. These failures are 100% consistent and still happen. I can see that SQL was restarted by Google a few hours before the issue started and I'm wondering if this is somehow related to whatever maintenance happened, SQL version upgrade? I'm unclear what version we had before Saturday, but it's now 11.6.

Interestingly enough, I can avoid the error if the file loaded into the table is under a certain size:

- 14,052 bytes (16 KB on disk): This fails every time.
- 14,051 bytes (16 KB on disk): This works every time.

I'd appreciate if someone from Google could confirm what took place during the maintenance window that might be causing this error. We are currently blocked by this as we load much larger datasets into the database than ~14 000 bytes.

Comment: I'll leave the question open in case Google has something to add, but it sounds like the recent Cloud SQL maintenance broke a number of things, likely including this one too. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/Tym-vhoHaxY

Answer (score 0):

FYI this was caused by a JDK issue with TLS v1.3, addressed in JDK 11.05. Google will likely upgrade the JDK used for the Cloud Functions JVMs from 11.04 to something newer next week. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221253